# which comes first, system proxy or VPN?

Tags: networking, proxy, vpn

If I used a vpn and a system proxy, how would the internet be accessed?

PC --> Proxy --> VPN --> Internet

--or--

PC --> VPN --> Proxy --> Internet

Answer (score 0):

let me tell you this way, your proxy settings will use your vpn settings, so world wide will recognize you as your proxy server IP, but proxy server will see you as your vpn address, and your vpn server will know who you are :)

Comment: proxy settings act like a simple program, but VPN act like it is a network connection

Comment: :( is there a way to configure the connection to go through the proxy first and then through the VPN? I have a hospital which uses a program called fortiguard. It blocks EVERYTHING. I can't even access my public library or my personal email as the library is labelled as terrorist content and my email is labelled as social media. I want to route my vpn through Tor as Tor seems to work but I want to be able to trust my exit node so I'll have to setup a hidden service where I will host my VPN.

Comment: I don'n think so, by what label your VPN server is blocked??

Comment: it's just blocked. I've tried different ports and a lot of other stuff